# Get size of specific repository in Nexus 2

Tags: repository, storage, nexus, space, nexus2

I am using Nexus version 2 and I am new in Nexus, can you help me to get the size of a specific repository in Nexus2 ? How can I get this information by UI or CLI ?
There are many differences between versions 2 and 3, please guide me for version 2.

Comment: Nexus2 stores it's repository content as raw files on disk (compared to Nexus3 which uses blobstores and a database). To get the size of an existing repo in Nexus2, login to your server, `cd` to the directory where your repo is stored then issue `du -shc *`.

Comment: thanks alot , How do I find repositories ? Where is the address of the repositories on Nexus 2?

Comment: Inside the directory configured to store your Nexus data.